# Bad: modifier in $ (/). on login in csh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, csh

I am getting this error(?) message every time I log into the server I am connecting to.  I also get it every time I run any C-shell program, multiple times if I use recursion.

It seemed to show up after I tried to set up my PATH variable with setenv, but I am not very familiar with this.

Do I need to reset my path back to the default? Is that even possible?
Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the relevant code and errors.

Comment: There really is no code associated with it.  It pops up as soon as I log in, and comes up as output for shell programs as simple as:

#
ls

Comment: Is that the whole error message? What operating system are you using? Which version of csh? More details are helpful.

Comment: It happened on Windows through Putty and on the computers on the linux server.

Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-18-generic x86_64)

Last login: Wed Mar 26 21:26:57 2014 from 99-140-88-225.lightspeed.bcvloh.sbcglobal.net
Bad : modifier in $ (/).